# How to prove that C(x,y) coordinates which have parameters satisfies inequation with two absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

I have two linear functions:

`f(x) = 2x - m + 6`

`g(x) = -x + 2m + 3`

I have to prove that for all `m belonging to real numbers` they intersects in C(x,y), and the coordinates must satisfy below inequation:

`|x - 1| - |5 - y| <= 1`

I did equation system and solved it using determinants, and my result is:

`x = 4m - 16`

`y = 4m - 20`

So point `C` will be `C(4m - 16, 4m - 20)`.

Determinants have one solution when main determinant is not equal to 0. I solved it and got `3 != 0`, so for `all real m` there is point of intersect. So I have proved first thing.

But I'm stuck on proving that coordinates of C satisfies inequality I mentioned earlier. I know it must be true, but when I try to prove it then some inequations occurs to be false (and I think they all will be true, maybe I'm wrong?). I tried to do it by writing absolute values as piecewise.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of the point of intersection are $(m - 1, m + 4)$ (instead of the values that you quote in your post).

With these values, you can find the following results for the inequation :
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for } m \le 1\\
3 - 2m & \text{for } 1 \lt m \lt 2\\
-1 &  \text{for } m \ge 2
\end{cases}

from which you can easily prove that the inequality is indeed satisfied.

Comment: Ah, because of the mess on the paper, I mixed up the results from different calculations. Thanks!